# Integrating a Real Function with the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I had a complex analysis final today where the following question was asked:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{k - \sin(\theta)}, k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq 2$$

You can use the residue theorem to find that it is $$\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{k^2 - 1}}$$
but I was wondering what happens for $k=1$? When I was trying to solve the problem you have that the singularities of the function after you put it in terms of $z = e^{it}$ are on the boundary of the unit circle for $k=1$, so I wasn't sure how to use the residue theorem in that case. So, my question is, how can you solve
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{1 - \sin(\theta)}$$

Comment: I don't think this is an integrable singularity even in the Cauchy principal value sense. I don't think you can assign a value to such an integral.

Comment: Note that, the case $k=1$ makes the integral kind of improper integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral blows up, which can also be seen from your result $\dfrac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{k^2-1}}$. This is because close to $\theta = \pi/2$, the integrand blows and the integral is no longer integrable. To see this, let us look at the integral in the vicinity of $\pi/2$.
$$\int_{\pi/2-a}^{\pi/2+a} \dfrac{d \theta}{1-\sin(\theta)} = \int_{-a}^a \dfrac{dx}{1-\sin(\pi/2+x)} = \int_{-a}^a \dfrac{dx}{1-\cos(x)}$$
where $a$ is a small positive number.
We have $$\cos(x) > 1-\dfrac{x^2}2 \implies 1-\cos(x) < \dfrac{x^2}2 \implies \dfrac1{1-\cos(x)} > \dfrac2{x^2}.$$
Hence, we have
$$\int_{-a}^a \dfrac{dx}{1-\cos(x)} > \int_{-a}^a \dfrac{2dx}{x^2}$$which clearly blows up.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the indefinite integral

$$ \int \frac{1}{1-\cos(\theta)} d \theta = -\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{1}{2}\theta)}. $$